# All hill-stations have a lake. Ooty has two lakes?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, propositional-calculus, predicate-logic, first-order-logic

> All hill-stations have a lake. Ooty has two lakes.

Which of the statement(s) below is/are logically valid and can be inferred from the above sentences?

$(i)$ Ooty is not a hill-station.

$(ii)$ No hill-station can have more than one lake.

1. $(i)$ only
2. $(ii)$ only
3. both $(i)$ and $(ii)$
4. neither
               $(i)$ nor $(ii)$

---

My attempt :

Statement $(i)$ can be false, since all hill-stations has lake, but if a city has lakes, that does not mean that city is a hill-station.

[image]

For statement $(ii)$, a lake means may be any lake means number is not given. I've not formal way, this statement given false.

> Can you explain in formal way, please?

Comment: If an indian sets the question its none of the above as Ooty IS a hill station

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the given statements,

> All hill-stations have a lake. Ooty has two lakes.

The above statements do not **strictly** imply any $1$ of the following:

> A. All hill-stations have exactly $1$ lake.
>
> B. All hill-stations have atmost a lake.
>
> C. All hill-stations have at least a lake.

$1.$ should be correct if interpretation $C.$ is absolutely true.

$2.$ should be correct if interpretation $B.$ is absolutely true.

$3.$ should be correct if interpretation $A.$ is absolutely true.

But the interpretations as mentioned are not **strictly** implied. Any $1$ of them might be true but which one ... it has not been stated directly.

Hence $4.$ is correct as it is most logical.

Comment: @MithleshUpadhayay I have edited my answer accordingly.